# Cannot bind arango 2.8.5 to to endpoint ssl://0.0.0.0:443

Tags: ssl, arangodb

I am using arangodb 2.8.5 on ubuntu 14.04 (64bit)

- In config file, endpoint = ssl://0.0.0.0:443
- fails to start with error msg in log "FATAL failed
  to bind to endpoint 'ssl://0.0.0.0:443'. Please check whether another
  instance is already running or review your endpoints configuration."
- Ran netstat -lnpt. Only port 22 is in use by ssh

  Server starts up and binds to port 8530 with ssl when using endpoint = ssl://0.0.0.0:8530. Admin website is accessible https://www.website.com:8530/.../

  I want the admin ui to be accessible without the need for additional port 8530 i.e. https://www.website.com/. This was possible to set up in the earlier versions. What am i doing wrong or is this not possible anymore?

Small application so i am trying to avoid running another web server in front to forward requests to arango apps. Thank you very much for any direction.

Regards,
Anjan

Comment: Something is listening on port 443. Did you specify it twice by any chance?

Comment: Ran netstat but no process seems to be using port 443. Is there a more comprehensive scan?

Comment: I read what you wrote, but you haven't read all I wrote.

Comment: Sorry about missing that. If i understand your question correctly, i checked the config file and there is only one line specifying endpoint

Comment: Do you start it as root? ports below 1024 demand being privileged in *nix

Comment: Good point, i am starting arangod as root.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs in conjunction with ArangoDB dropping its root privileges to the specified user by

```
[server]
endpoint = ssl://0.0.0.0:443
uid=arangodb
```

This may become possible with ArangoDB 3.0 again, however currently you have to [choose one of the workarounds to allow non-root processes to bind lower ports](/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l):

1. [authbind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind)
2. [Using the iptables REDIRECT target to redirect a low port to a high port](http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#REDIRECTTARGET) (the "nat" table is not yet implemented for ip6tables, the IPv6 version of iptables)
3. SELinux or AppArmor
4. Use the capabilities system available as of Linux kernel 2.6.24 and `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability:

   `setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/sbin/arangod`

   And then anytime ArangoDB is executed thereafter it will get the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability. `setcap` is in the debian package `libcap2-bin`.

   More details on the capabilities can be found at:

   - [capabilities(7) man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). Read this long and hard if you're going to use capabilities in a production environment. There are some really tricky details of how capabilities are inherited across exec() calls that are detailed here.
   - [setcap man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html)
   - ["Bind ports below 1024 without root on GNU/Linux"](http://www.wensley.org.uk/info#setpcaps)